# Improve speed pytesseract OCR

Tags: python, performance, ocr, tesseract

I am using pytesseract v.0.1.5 with tesseract v.3.02.02 to analyse large sets of jpeg images. The quality is very good but the speed is a bit of a problem.

In my setup (i5-4460, 8GB Ram) it takes the OCR around 25 seconds to process 100 images (1900x250). On the same machine, Matlab 2014b OCR, which is also based on google's tesseract code, is 30% faster.

Is there anyway to modify the settings of the OCR (e.g. remove unwanted dictionaries) to make it faster? My text only contains English, numbers and special characters `/` and `-`.

I am using the command via the standard way:

`pytesseract.image_to_string(im)`

Thanks a lot,

Harry

Answer (score 1):

pytesseract is a thin wrapper for tesseract cli, if you don't really need python api just call plain tesseract. Using a wrapper you are adding overhead. How much i don't know, depending on your platform you have different profiling tools to measure that. On linux there's perf: `perf record yourcommand` to record and `perf report` to see the results.

As you can see from the code, you can restrict the language to only english, you can profile again to see if it does make any difference.
https://github.com/madmaze/pytesseract/blob/master/src/pytesseract.py#L128

Comment: Riccardo, I followed the link you provided and changed language to 'Eng' and also tried playing with the config option following the instruction in [http://tesseract-ocr.googlecode.com/svn-history/r719/trunk/doc/tesseract.1.html](http://tesseract-ocr.googlecode.com/svn-history/r719/trunk/doc/tesseract.1.html). None seemed to make any difference..

Comment: I wouldn't think the thin wrapper is making much difference in performance. The tesseract function call itself is very expensive.